# Windows cmd.exe output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a script for remotely executing commands on other machines, however... when using windows cmd.exe commands It does not write to the file on the remote server. Here is the code.

```
$server = 'serverName'  
$Username = 'userName'  
$Password = 'passWord'  
$cmd = "cmd /c ipconfig"  

########################  

########################  

$ph = "C:\mPcO.txt"  
$rph = "\\$server\C$\mPcO.txt"  

$cmde = "$cmd > $ph"  
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force  
$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist  "$Username",$pass  
Invoke-WmiMethod win32_process -name create -ComputerName $server -ArgumentList $cmde  Credential $mycred  
cmd /c net use \\$server\C$ $password /USER:$username  
Get-Content $rph  
Remove-Item $rph  
cmd /c net use \\$server\C$ /delete
```

As you can see we simply write

```
$cmde = "$cmd > $ph"
```

if I use a PowerShell command I use

```
$cmde = "$cmd | Out-File $ph"
```

and it works fine. Any advice Appreciated

Answer (score 5):

Why are you doing it the hard way? You can use WMI to get the IP details of a remote computer.

```
Get-WMIObject -ComputerName "RemoteServer" Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled=$true" | Out-File $env:TEMP\ipdetails.txt
```

Now, once you have that file, you can move it using the commands you had in your script.

Comment: Im not worried about the IP, thats just an example I gave for a non powershell command.

Comment: Hmm.that should have been clear. Anyway, the script works fine for me except the missing '-' in `Invoke-WMIMethod` line. `-Credential` is missing '-'. Other than that, the script was able to create a file on the remote machine with (`$cmd > $ph`) and I was able to read it using `Get-Content $rph`.

Comment: BTW, you don't have to map network drive to a remote conputer. Get-Item supports UNC paths.

Comment: For that matter, the OP doesn't need the `cmd /c` on `cmd /c net use ...`. `net use ...` works just fine from PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks guys, also, strangly this does work on one setup, executing from XP to win7, however when executing from a win7 machine back to XP it does not. It is also not working from 7 to 2k3.